# Spring AMQP Integration - Consumer Manual Acknowledgement

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-integration, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I am testing `Spring-AMQP` with `Spring-Integration` support, I've following configuration and test:

```
<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory" />
<rabbit:queue name="durableQ"/>
<int:channel id="consumingChannel">
    <int:queue capacity="2"/> <!-- Message get Acked as-soon-as filled in Q -->
</int:channel>

<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter 
    channel="consumingChannel"
    queue-names="durableQ" 
    connection-factory="connectionFactory"
    concurrent-consumers="1"
    acknowledge-mode="AUTO"
    />


public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println("Starting consumer with integration..");
    AbstractApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
    "classpath:META-INF/spring/integration/spring-integration-context-consumer.xml");

    PollableChannel consumingChannel = context.getBean("consumingChannel",   
                                                          PollableChannel.class);           
        int count = 0;
        while (true) {
            Message<?> msg = consumingChannel.receive(1000);
            System.out.println((count++) + " \t -> " + msg);

            try { //sleep to check number of messages in queue
                Thread.sleep(50000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

In this configuration it was evident that as soon as message arrives at `consumingChannel` they are Acked and hence removed from queue. I validated this by placing a high `sleep` after `receive` and check `queue-size`. There are no further control on it.

Now if I set `acknowledge-mode=MANUAL`, there are no ways seems to do manual `ack` via spring integration.

My need is to process message and after processing do a `manual-ack` so till `ack` message remains persisted at `durableQ`.

Is there any way to handle `MANUAL` ack with `spring-amqp-integration`? I want to avoid passing `ChannelAwareMessageListener` to `inbound-channel-adapter` since I want to have control of consumer's `receive`.

**Update:**

It even doesn't seems to be possible when using own `listener-container` with `inbound-channel-adapter`:

```
// Below creates a default direct-channel (spring-integration channel) named "adapter", to receive poll this channel which is same as above
<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter id="adapter" listener-container="amqpListenerContainer" /> 

<bean id="amqpListenerContainer" class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
    <property name="queueNames" value="durableQ" />
    <property name="acknowledgeMode" value="MANUAL" />

// messageListener not allowed when using with adapter, so no way of having own ChannelAwareMessageListener, so no channel exposed onMessage, hence no way to ack
    <property name="messageListener" ref="listener"/>
</bean>
<bean id="listener" class="com.sd.springint.rmq.MsgListener"/>
```

Above configuration throws error as `messageListener` property is not allowed, see inline comment on tag. So purpose of using `listner-container` got defeated (for exposing `channel` via `ChannelAwareMessageListener`).

To me `spring-integration` cannot be used for `manual-acknowledgement` (I know, this is a hard saying!),  Can anyone help me in validating this or Is there any specific approach/configuration required for this which I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is because you are using async handoff using a `QueueChannel`. It is generally better to control the concurrency in the container (`concurrent-consumers="2"`) and don't do any async handoffs in your flow (use `DirectChannel`s). That way, AUTO ack will work just fine. Instead of receiving from the `PollableChannel` subscribe a `new MessageHandler()` to a `SubscribableChannel`.

**Update:**

You normally don't need to deal with Messages in an SI application, but the equivalent of your test with a DirectChannel would be...

```
    SubscribableChannel channel = context.getBean("fromRabbit", SubscribableChannel.class);

    channel.subscribe(new MessageHandler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
            System.out.println("Got " + message);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Ok so `PollableChannel` isn't what I require (and that's logical), but are you suggesting that both `DirectChannel` and `SubscribableChannel` can fit in my requirement, I am bit confused here? And how/when does `ack` happen in these cases? Meantime I am trying out these approaches..

Comment: `DirectChannel` is an implementation of `SubscribableChannel` (just like `QueueChannel` is an implementation of `PollableChannel`.

Comment: I should have tried before posting above comment, my bad! It worked perfectly fine. So basically take-away for me is 1) `MANUAL` mode shouldn't be used in `spring-amqp-integration` (mainly with `int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter`) as consumer's underlying `channels` are not exposed AND 2) use `DirectChannel` and `concurrent-consumer` property. Thanks alot, your help is much appreciated.

Comment: I Updated my answer to show how; the ack occurs when the thread exits the `handleMessage` method.

Answer (score 0):

MANUAL Ack is allowed only via `Channel.basicAck()`. So, you should have an access to the `Channel`, on which your message was received.

Try to play with `advice-chain` of `<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter>`:

1. Implement some `Advice` as `MethodBeforeAdvice`
2. The `advice-chain` on Container is applied for `ContainerDelegate#invokeListener`
3. The first argument of that method is exactly a `Channel`
4. Suppose you can place to the `MessageProperties.headers` that `Channel` within that `Advice`
5. And configure `<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter>` with `mapped-request-headers` to that `Channel`.
6. And in the end try to invoke `basicAck()` on that `Channel` header from Spring Integration Message in the any place of your downstream flow.

Comment: @Artem Bilan Can you post code for advice chain for code while using amqp:channel instead of inbound channel adapter?

Comment: The `int-amqp:channel` has a `advice-chain` attribute. What the problem do you have with that? This really plays the same role here as that one on the `int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter`