# Spring integration: how to handle exceptions in services after an aggregator?

Tags: spring-integration, amqp

I have an application relying on Spring Integration (4.0.4.RELEASE) and RabbitMQ. My flow is as follow:

Messages are put in queue via a process (they do not expect any answer):
Gateway -> Channel -> RabbitMQ

And then drained by another process:

```
RabbitMQ --1--> inbound-channel-adapter A --2--> chain B --3--> aggregator C --4--> service-activator D --5--> final service-activator E
```

## Explanations & context

The specific thing is that nowhere in my application I am using a splitter: **aggregator C** just waits for enough messages to come, or for a timeout to expire, and then forwards the batch to **service D**. Messages can get stuck in **aggregator C** for quite a long time, and should NOT be considered as consumed there. They should only be consumed once **service D** successfully completes. Therefore, I am using MANUAL acknowledgement on **inbound-channel-adapter A** and **service E** is in charge of acknowledging the batch.

### Custom aggregator

I solved the acknowledgement issue I had when set to AUTO by redefining the aggregator. Indeed, messages are acknowledged immediately if any asynchronous process occurs in the flow (see question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21043754/spring-amqp-integration-consumer-manual-acknowledgement)). Therefore, I switched to MANUAL acknowledgement and implemented the aggregator like this:

```
     <bean class="org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean">
        <property name="inputChannel" ref="channel3"/>
        <property name="handler">
            <bean class="org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AggregatingMessageHandler">
                <constructor-arg name="processor">
                    <bean class="com.test.AMQPAggregator"/>
                </constructor-arg>
                <property name="correlationStrategy">
                    <bean class="com.test.AggregatorDefaultCorrelationStrategy" />
                </property>
                <property name="releaseStrategy">
                    <bean class="com.test.AggregatorMongoReleaseStrategy" />
                </property>
                <property name="messageStore" ref="messageStoreBean"/>
                <property name="expireGroupsUponCompletion" value="true"/>
                <property name="sendPartialResultOnExpiry" value="true"/>
                <property name="outputChannel" ref="channel4"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageStoreBean" class="org.springframework.integration.store.SimpleMessageStore"/>

    <bean id="messageStoreReaperBean" class="org.springframework.integration.store.MessageGroupStoreReaper">
        <property name="messageGroupStore" ref="messageStore" />
        <property name="timeout" value="${myapp.timeout}" />
    </bean>

    <task:scheduled-tasks>
        <task:scheduled ref="messageStoreReaperBean" method="run" fixed-rate="2000" />
    </task:scheduled-tasks>
```

I wanted indeed to aggregate the headers in a different way, and keep the highest value of all the *amqp_deliveryTag* for later multi-acknoledgement in **service E** (see [this](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/114876-overwriting-aggregateheaders) thread). This works great so far, apart from the fact that it is far more verbose than the typical *aggregator* namespace (see [this](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-2480) old Jira ticket).

### Services

I am just using basic configurations:

**chain-B**

```
<int:chain input-channel="channel2" output-channel="channel3">
        <int:header-enricher>
            <int:error-channel ref="errorChannel" /> // Probably useless
        </int:header-enricher>
        <int:json-to-object-transformer/>
        <int:transformer    ref="serviceABean" 
                            method="doThis" />
        <int:transformer    ref="serviceBBean" 
                            method="doThat" />
    </int:chain>
```

**service-D**

```
<int:service-activator  ref="serviceDBean"
                            method="doSomething"
                            input-channel="channel4"
                            output-channel="channel5" />
```

### Error management

As I rely on MANUAL acknowledgement, I need to manually reject messages as well in case an exception occurs. I have the following definition for **inbound-channel-adapter A**:

```
<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter   channel="channel2"
                                            queue-names="si.queue1"
                                            error-channel="errorChannel"
                                            mapped-request-headers="*"
                                            acknowledge-mode="MANUAL"
                                            prefetch-count="${properties.prefetch_count}"
                                            connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory"/>
```

I use the following definition for **errorChannel**:

```
<int:chain input-channel="errorChannel">
            <int:transformer ref="errorUnwrapperBean" method="unwrap" />
            <int:service-activator ref="amqpAcknowledgerBean" method="rejectMessage" />
</int:chain>
```

ErrorUnwrapper is based on [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/intermediate/errorhandling/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/samples/errorhandling/ErrorUnwrapper.java) code and the whole exception detection and message rejection works well until messages reach **aggregator C**.

## Problem

If an exception is raised while processing the messages in **service-activator D**, then I see this exception but **errorChannel** does not seem to receive any message, and my *ErrorUnwrapper* *unwrap()* method is not called. The tailored stack traces I see when an *Exception("ahahah")* is thrown are as follow:

```
2014-09-23 16:41:18,725 ERROR o.s.i.s.SimpleMessageStore:174: Exception in expiry callback
org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: java.lang.Exception: ahahaha
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:78)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler.handleRequestMessage(ServiceActivatingHandler.java:71)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:170)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78)
(...)

Caused by: java.lang.Exception: ahahaha
    at com.myapp.ServiceD.doSomething(ServiceD.java:153)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
(...)

2014-09-23 16:41:18,733 ERROR o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler:95: Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.
org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: java.lang.Exception: ahahaha
(...)
```

## Question

How can one tell the services that process messages coming from such an aggregator to publish errors to **errorChannel**? I tried to specify in the header via a *header-enricher* the *error-channel* with no luck. I am using the default **errorChannel** definition, but I tried as well to change its name and redefine it. I am clueless here, and even though I found [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate/errorhandling) and [that](http://xpadro.blogspot.se/2013/11/how-error-handling-works-in-spring.html), I have not managed to get it to work. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you see by StackTrace your process is started from the `MessageGroupStoreReaper` Thread, which is initiated from the default `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler`.

So, you must provide a custom bean for that:

```
<bean id="scheduler" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler">
    <property name="errorHandler">
        <bean class="org.springframework.integration.channel.MessagePublishingErrorHandler">
            <property name="defaultErrorChannel" ref="errorChannel"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="scheduler">
    <task:scheduled ref="messageStoreReaperBean" method="run" fixed-rate="2000" />
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

However I see the benefits from having the `error-channel` on the `<aggregator>`, where we really have several points from different detached Threads, with wich we can't get deal normally.

Comment: Thanks Artem, it works! I tried almost everything but not this. This is however annoying in case we rely elsewhere in the code (and in the same context) on another `TaskScheduler` (typically, the one created via `@EnableScheduling`-like annotations). Spring 4 will complain then. I fixed it by using `SchedulingConfigurer`, but having a direct support for header aggregation and error channel built-in aggregator components would be great to avoid those extra code lines!

Comment: Eh.. What is bad that in all those `async` cases we provide `MessagePublishingErrorHandler` to the `scheduler/executor` on the entry point before `Runnable.run()` to catch all underlying Exception. That means to catch exceptions a bit deeper (in our case in the Aggregator) would be like breaking concept. However I think `errorChannel` for the `MessageGroupStoreReaper` would be enough. you can raise a JIRA issue on the matter and we'll think what to further.