# How to manual ack on AMQP-Backed Channel

Tags: spring-integration, spring-amqp

I'm using an AMQP-Backed channel in my workflow and I would like to handle ACK manually.
I though this could be done as in the AMQP Inbound Channel where you get reference of the AMQP Client Channel in the Message Header but I do not find the Header AmqpHeaders.CHANNEL in the message. Here is how I've setup my AmqpChannelFactoryBean :

```
@Bean(name = AMQP_BACKED_CHANNEL)
    public AmqpChannelFactoryBean pubSub(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        AmqpChannelFactoryBean factoryBean = new AmqpChannelFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        factoryBean.setQueueName(AMQP_BACKED_CHANNEL);
        factoryBean.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.MANUAL);
        factoryBean.setPubSub(false);
        factoryBean.setExtractPayload(true);

        return factoryBean;
    }
```

My feeling is that I should not use the same approach as in AMQP Inbound Channel but cannot find documentation out there. Anyone can help, please?

Answer (score 0):

Little update: Not sure if this is the "proper" way to do it but inspired by the comment of Artem Bilam in this post [Spring AMQP Integration - Consumer Manual Acknowledgement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21043754/spring-amqp-integration-consumer-manual-acknowledgement) I've resolved using a MethodBeforeAdvice. Basically my MethodBeforeAdvice is applied to the invokeListener() method of the SimpleMessageListenerContainer created by the AmqpChannelFactoryBean therefore I can get hold of the Amqp Client Channel and amqp headers and the game is done! Below is my code modified (just a bit concise for the sake of a clearer reading):

```
@Bean(name = AMQP_BACKED_CHANNEL)
public AmqpChannelFactoryBean amqpBackedChannel(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    AmqpChannelFactoryBean factoryBean = new AmqpChannelFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    factoryBean.setQueueName(AMQP_BACKED_CHANNEL);
    factoryBean.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.MANUAL);
    factoryBean.setPubSub(false);
    factoryBean.setExtractPayload(true);
    factoryBean.setConcurrentConsumers(5);
    MethodBeforeAdvice methodBeforeAdvice = new MethodBeforeAdvice() {
        @Override public void before(Method method, Object[] args, Object target)
            throws Throwable {
            Channel amqpClientChannel = (Channel) args[0];
            Message amqpCoreMessage = (Message) args[1];
            Map<String, Object>
                amqpCoreMessageHeaders =  amqpCoreMessage.getMessageProperties().getHeaders();
            amqpCoreMessageHeaders.put(AmqpHeaders.CHANNEL,amqpClientChannel);
        }
    };

    factoryBean.setAdviceChain(new Advice[]{methodBeforeAdvice});

    return factoryBean;
}
```